# Can you put your YouTube handle on a passenger vehicle

Tags: advertisements, motor-vehicle

I have a friend who is just starting an outdoor travel YouTube channel with the intention of making money. They are not currently registered as an LLC (or anything). Their camera and video editing equipment is stored in their van and they regularly film and edit in the van. Watching many of the videos would make this obvious. They are also planning on putting a modest sized sticker on the back door with their YouTube channel. The van is registered as a passenger vehicle in Massachusetts, although they will be frequently traveling out of state. I told them they may need to register the van as a commercial vehicle.

They were dismissive until I mention the channel advertisement on a passenger vehicle may provide the police probable cause to search the vehicle during either a traffic stop or even be grounds to pull them over. My friend would prefer the police not search their vehicle because the police may find illegal substances.

1. Does the vehicle need to be registered as a commercial vehicle and if so is it the ad or the use of it in their videos
2. Does signage on a passenger vehicle provide probably cause for a stop and/or search

Answer (score 0):

It is not a crime to have a YouTube channel, or to operate a business, or to travel out of state. Putting an advertisement on a car is also not a crime. As for the question of a search, the police would not even have a legal basis for stopping a vehicle for having an advertisement, much less searching it. If the person was speeding or drunk-driving, or even if there was a random sobriety checkpoint, they could be stopped, but still to conduct a search, they either need consent, or probable cause that the vehicle contains evidence of a crime.

A "commercial vehicle" is not "a vehicle used by a person on their job", it is one used to transport goods or people if it weighs more that 10K lbs GVW, hauls more than 8 people for money or 15 people not for money or to transport hazardous materials, so unless we're missing details, this is not a commercial vehicle. There are state-level definitions regarding vehicle ownership, i.e. whether the vehicle is registered in the name of a corporation rather than a human.

Comment: MA 540 CMR 2.05(f) says that "a vehicle which has business advertisements or business markings thereon" must have commercial plates. That seems like it makes it a "crime" and potentially, but I don't know, that that first crime would provide probable cause to search for a crime associated with transport of goods in a non-commercial vehicle.

Comment: @StrongBad that is not a crime but a code violation, which is a misdemeanor.

Comment: @StrongBad- Does your referenced CMR not answer your question?

Comment: @MichaelHall well they are not a business yet so I don't know if it applies. Also I don't know if it means they can be stopped or searched.

Answer (score 0):

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

### Usage is determined by … usage

Under the [Motor Vehicles Taxation Regulation](https://legislation.nsw.gov.au/view/whole/html/inforce/current/sl-2016-0516#sch.1-sec.1) 2016, annual tax is higher for business vehicles than for personal vehicle on the basis that business vehicles are, in general, used more and therefore cause more wear and tear on the road infrastructure,

A private vehicle is “used substantially for private purposes” and a general business vehicle is “Not a lower taxed motor vehicle and not used substantially for private purposes” (there are specific concessional taxes for specific types of business use but we don’t need to know about them).

Failing to pay the full amount of the tax is an offence attracting a fine of 5 penalty units (currently $550).

So, if your friend uses their vehicle “substantially for private purposes” and only secondarily for business purposes, they do not need to register as a business vehicle. If their private use is not “substantial” they do.

### Insurance

Whether they are covered by their insurance depends on the wording of the policy and if they were upfront and honest when they took out or renewed their policy.

Whether they have uses the correct registration category  is part of this disclosure obligation but it is not determinative on its own.